# Jekyll collections: process markdown within a plugin

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to adapt an existing Jekyll plugin (taken from [here](https://github.com/jgarber623/sixtwothree.org/blob/master/src/_plugins/json_page_generator.rb)) in order to generate a `.json` version of every document in a `collection`.

However, I'm having trouble getting my content to convert from markdown to HTML (which I would then like to convert/encode into JSON). In Jekyll, a collection "document" is different from a "post", and while `posts` have access to a `transform` method that does what I need, it looks like "documents" do not.

Is there some other straight-forward way to feed content to a markdown parser in the context of a Jekyll plug-in?

Here's the plug-in code I've been working with so far. This is generating JSON, but markdown is not being converted into HTML (markdown syntax like `**` remains in the file).

```rb
module Jekyll
  class JSONPage < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, name, content)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir  = dir
      @name = name

      self.data = {}
      self.content = content

      process(@name)
    end

    def read_yaml(*)
      # Do nothing
    end

    def render_with_liquid?
      false
    end
  end

  class JSONPageGenerator < Generator
    safe true

    def generate(site)
      site.documents.each do |document|
        # Set the path of the JSON version
        path = "#{document.collection.label}" + document.cleaned_relative_path + ".json"
        output = document.to_liquid

        # Delete unnecessary metadata
        ['layout', 'output'].each { |key| output.delete(key) }

        site.pages << JSONPage.new(site, site.source, File.dirname(path), File.basename(path), output)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out the answer is simple – you can just `require 'kramdown'` or any other markdown generator directly in the plugin.

```rb
module Jekyll
  class JSONPage < Page
    def initialize(site, base, dir, name, content)
      @site = site
      @base = base
      @dir  = dir
      @name = name

      self.data = {}
      self.content = content

      process(@name)
    end

    def read_yaml(*)
      # Do nothing
    end

    def render_with_liquid?
      false
    end
  end

  class JSONPostGenerator < Generator
    safe true

    def generate(site)
      require 'kramdown'

      site.documents.each do |document|
        # Set the path of the JSON version
        path = "#{document.collection.label}" + document.cleaned_relative_path + ".json"
        output = document.to_liquid
        output['content'] = Kramdown::Document.new(document.content).to_html.gsub(/\n/, "")

        # Delete unnecessary metadata
        ['layout', 'output'].each { |key| output.delete(key) }


        site.pages << JSONPage.new(site, site.source, File.dirname(path), File.basename(path), output.to_json)
      end
    end
  end
end
```